# Multivariate Non-Differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

[This example](http://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives!) says that "continuous partial derivatives imply differentiability but not vice-versa". Based on [transposition logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(logic)!), I would then assume that if a multivariate function has discontinuous partials at a certain point, then the function is not differentiable at that point.  Is this the right interpretation?

Any guidance would be appreciated -- thanks.

Comment: I'm confused about trying to show the partials are discontinuous versus showing that the directional derivative in a certain direction doesn't exist.

Comment: What's the exact problem?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanGafar for the clarification. I'm confused about the existence of partials and the -discountinuity of partials at a certain point in trying to show that a function is not differentiable at that point

Comment: I see that differentiable (total derivative exists) $\implies$ directional derivatives exist $\implies$ partial derivatives exist but am hung up on how continuity factors in...

Comment: Differentiable implies continuous. Are you confused about why this is true? EDIT: You aren't completely clear on what you are asking.

Comment: I see for this that we can multiply $f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{y})$ by $\frac{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}}$, convert the limit into a limit involving the derivative, and use that as a constant to show that as $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{y}$ we get the limit goes to zero. But I'm confused why discountinuous partials do not imply that the function is not differentiable at the point. (I took a look through the link but it hasn't sunk in yet)

Comment: Think that I am confused about the roles of existence and continuity

Comment: Editing question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Discontinuous partial derivatives do not imply that the function is not differentiable. See this link for a counter example: http://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives